# Movie where, at the end, the main character is sent back in time to the day he met his wife

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

This is a movie I saw when I was a kid, but I really can't remember what year it was; probably between 2000 and 2006. It was in color and most probably in DVD format. I saw it in French, but I have no idea if it was a translation or not.

I absolutely can't remember what the story was about, but I remember the end. Somehow, the main character did something good, and as a reward he is sent back in time to the day he met his wife, who I think died/was killed at the beginning of the movie. In the scene, he is suddenly sent back to his car, driving. A dog crosses the road and he hits it. He stops the car and goes to see the dog, then takes it in his arms and looks around. He notices an animal clinic and rushes to it with the dog, and here he meets (again) the vet who is his wife. I'm also pretty sure they adopted the dog and we see it at the beginning of the movie.

I did a lot of research to find out what this movie could be, mostly on [Tropedia](https://tropedia.fandom.com/wiki/Tropedia), [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/) and [The Quintessential List of Time Travel Cinematic Movies](http://www.lara.on.ca/%7Eboxall/index.html), but to no avail.

It's not *The Time Traveler's Wife*.

Comment: The title alone reminded me of the entire movie.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is ***[The One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_(2001_film))*** (2001).

> The film, which deals with the concept of multiverses and interdimensional travel, follows Gabriel Yulaw (Jet Li), a rogue agent who travels to parallel realities in order for him to kill other versions of himself to become a mythical super-being known as "The One". Li plays a dual role as Yulaw and Gabe Law, an LASD deputy sheriff who teams up with a multiverse agent to prevent Yulaw from becoming the One.

The film isn't about time-travel, but rather travel between parallel universes. Jet Li plays multiple alternate universe versions of the same character, including both the protagonist, Gabe Law, and the antagonist, Yulaw.

In his native universe, Gabe married a woman named T.K., who dies during the events of the film. It's explained that they met when he brought a dog that was hit by a car to the animal hospital she worked at. They subsequently adopted the dog, Ollie, as their pet.

> GABE LAW: That day, I first saw her in the clinic... I came in with a dog that was hit by a car. I knew right away she was my center. She made me whole.

Near the end of the film, Gabe is transported to another universe where he encounters an alternate version of T.K. who's never met any version of him before. The circumstances of this meeting mirror the circumstances in which he met his universe's version of T.K., right down to an alternate version of Ollie being hit by a car. This may imply that he was transported to an earlier point in the timeline of this universe, but that wasn't specified.

You can view the relevant scene at around the 1:31 mark in the video clip below.

Comment: Oh woah, that must be it! Funny how my memory remember some details differently, but given the scene, it must be it. Thank you, I've been looking for the name of this movie for years!